# Delete chip in react js Material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I worked with react-js and Material-ui chip
I added many chips and Then a chip shows up with the text. I want to have the functionality to delete the chip.  but I cant how to delete it.

how can I delete it with `onDelete={}`?

here is just part of my code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, Component } from 'react'
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex'
  },
  chip: {
    backgroundColor: '#104d56'
  },
}))


  const handleDelete = () => {
       console.log(hashtag);
    };

const studentlist = []

function ResponsiveDrawer(props) {
{
    namefamily.map((item, index) => {
      if (index + 1 > namefamily.length - gpcapacity) {
        if (showstu == item[2]) {
          studentlist.push(
            <Chip

              key={item[2]}
              className={classes.chip}
              clickable={false}
              variant="outlined"
              label={
                <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary">
                  {item[0]} {item[1]}
                </Typography>
              }
              onDelete={handele}
              icon={<FaceIcon />}
            />
          )
        } else
          studentlist.push(
            <Chip
              key={item[2]}
              variant="outlined"
              clickable={true}
              label={
                <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary">
                  {item[0]} {item[1]}
                </Typography>
              }

              icon={<FaceIcon />}
            />
          )
      }
    })
  }
}
```

what will be inside of `handleDelete()` Function?

Comment: here is the official [documentation](https://codesandbox.io/s/93bfb?file=/demo.js:829-840).

Answer (score 2):

#### As per my understanding

1. `namefamily` is an array of array i.e. `[['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]`
2. you want to skip some student chips using `if (index + 1 > namefamily.length - gpcapacity) {` condition
3. allow delete chips for `showstu` student using `showstu == item[2]` condition

#### Ans: You `ResponsiveDrawer` looks like

see my comment in code for more details.

```
const ResponsiveDrawer = () => {
//considering you are getting showstu and gpcapacity as props or from somewhere

  const classes = useStyles();
  // point 2. you can skip here instead of checking if everytime
  const [chipData, setChipData] = React.useState(
     namefamily.slice(0, ((namefamily.length - 2) - gpcapacity))
   );

  const handleDelete = (chipToDelete) => {
    setChipData((chips) => chips.filter((chip) => chip[2] !== chipToDelete));
  };

  return (
       chipData.map((item, index) => {
        let chipProps = { clickable:true };
        //point 3. allowing delete to those who is {showstu}
        if (showstu == item[2]) {
          chipProps.onDelete = () => handleDelete(item[2]);
          chipProps.className = classes.chip;
          chipProps.clickable = false;
        }

        return (
          <Chip
              //for key better to use index as a unique
              key={index}
              // this is spread operator (https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) 
              {...chipProps}
              variant="outlined"
              label={
                <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary">
                  {item[0]} {item[1]}
                </Typography>
              }
              icon={<FaceIcon />}
            />
        );
      })
  );
}
```