# delete item in react (chip tag)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hey I have a problem with remove element in react. After click on delete button it doesn't delete and it is a chip tag

here is my code:

> ```
> import React, { useEffect, useState, Component } from 'react'
> import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip'
>
> const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
>   root: {
>     display: 'flex'
>   },
>   chip: {
>     backgroundColor: '#104d56'
>   },
> }))
>
>
>    let handleDelete = (chipToDelete) => {
>
>
>     setStudentlist(studentlist.filter((chip) => chip.key != chipToDelete))
>
>
>
>   }
>
>
> const studentlist = []
>
> function ResponsiveDrawer(props) {
> {
>     namefamily.map((item, index) => {
>       if (index + 1 > namefamily.length - gpcapacity) {
>         if (showstu == item[2]) {
>           studentlist.push(
>             <Chip
>
>               key={item[2]}
>               className={classes.chip}
>               clickable={false}
>               variant="outlined"
>               label={
>                 <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary">
>                   {item[0]} {item[1]}
>                 </Typography>
>               }
>               onDelete={handele}
>               icon={<FaceIcon />}
>             />
>           )
>         } else
>           studentlist.push(
>             <Chip
>               key={item[2]}
>               variant="outlined"
>               clickable={true}
>               label={
>                 <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary">
>                   {item[0]} {item[1]}
>                 </Typography>
>               }
>
>               icon={<FaceIcon />}
>             />
>           )
>       }
>     })
>   }
> }
> ```

and I have two `chip` tag ,

the first is in the normal style and the second is when I hover on button, the background color of chip will be changed .

nothing changes when I press delete button,

help me please

Comment: I hope it's not the simple typo `onDelete={handele}`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete chip in react js Material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979220/delete-chip-in-react-js-material-ui)